# result variable not accessbile in HtmlHelper inside Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, powerbi

I have an MVC web project. In a cshtml page of the project, I have an Ajax code as below:-

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("Report", "Report")',

        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                alert(result.AccessToken);  // ----> result.AccessToken is accessible here
                $("#load-report").html(@Html.PowerBIReportFor(m => m.Report, new { id = "pbi-report", style = "height:68vh", powerbi_access_token = result.AccessToken }));            // ----> result.AccessToken is not accessible here        
            }
            else {
                alert("server Error: Not able to load report, please try again");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in uploading the data");
        }
    });
```

The response to Ajax call is a JSON serialised object which has two data memebers - **Report** and **AccessToken**. In the success function of Ajax, the alert is able to access the result.AccessToken and prints it correctly. However, when I try to access result.AccessToken inside Html.PowerBIReportFor() function, the page shows an error saying "The name result does not exist in the current context".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What you have to remember is that the call to Html.PowerBIReportFor() is rendered **on the server**. It will have no knowledge of the JavaScript on your page. I'm not familiar with the PowerBIReportFor() but one option would be to load the report into a javascript variable, then do your AJAX call for the access token. If it's successful, put the report output into your document and then set the powerbi_access_token attribute using JQuery.attr()

Comment: Thanks JohnMorgan.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.PowerBIReportFor(m => m.Report, new { id = "pbi-report", style = "height:68vh", powerbi_access_token = Model.AccessToken });

The **PowerBIReportFor** method takes Model object coming from controller. The Model object should contain **Report** (Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V1.Models.Report) and **AccessToken** (string) so that the method dynamically builds a div element using the info. to generate attributes.

This works peacefully if a view is loaded from a controller. However in my case I just want to load the report into current view. If I load partial view entire Layout is loading again.

I finally solved this problem by building the div element by myself from the content of Result object in ajax success event.